# EXT: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, extjs, ext.net

I have a dropdown field and I am trying to reload its store on AfterRender but I receive this error:

> Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

Here is the code:

Javascript reload:

```
function LoadAll(){
    #{StoreFieldNames}.reload();
}
```

Ext Code:

Window afterRender:

```
<AfterRender Handler="LoadAll();" />
```

DropDownField editor in Gridpanel

```
<ext:DropDownField
     ID="DropDownField2"
     runat="server"
     FieldLabel="Field Name">
          <Component>
               <ext:GridPanel ID="FieldNameGridPanel"
                   runat="server"
                   Frame="true">
                       <Store>
                          <ext:Store ID="StoreFieldNames" runat="server" GroupField="Form" OnReadData="StoreFieldNames_ReadData">
                              <Model>
                                  <ext:Model ID="ModelFieldNames" runat="server">
                                      <Fields>
                                          <ext:ModelField Name="Form" />
                                          <ext:ModelField Name="FieldName" />
                                      </Fields>
                                  </ext:Model>
                              </Model>
                          </ext:Store>
                      </Store>
                      <ColumnModel runat="server">
                          <Columns>
                          <ext:Column runat="server" Text="Form" DataIndex="Form" Flex="6" />
                          <ext:Column runat="server" DataIndex="FieldName" Flex="6" />                                                               
                          <ext:ImageCommandColumn runat="server" Align="Center" Flex="1">
                               <Commands>
                                     <ext:ImageCommand Icon="Accept" CommandName="Pick">
                                            <ToolTip Text="Click to choose this fieldname" />
                                     </ext:ImageCommand>
                               </Commands>
                               <Listeners>
                                  <Command Handler="this.gridRef.dropDownField.setValue(record.data.FieldName);" />
                               </Listeners>

                           </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
                       </Columns>
                  </ColumnModel>
                  <View>
                      <ext:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" LoadMask="true" />
                  </View>

                  <SelectionModel>
                       <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel3" runat="server" Mode="Multi" />
                  </SelectionModel>

                  <Features>
                       <ext:Grouping ID="Grouping3 runat="server" HideGroupedHeader="true" StartCollapsed="true" />
                  </Features>
               </ext:GridPanel>
            </Component>
      </ext:DropDownField>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

In ExtJs docs provide method to get store for combo and store have method to **load** data. You can refer [ExtJs docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#placeholder-simple-getStore)

I have create small demo to show you, how it work. [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26l0)

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [
        'id','email', 'first', 'last'
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'person.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'local',
    margin:20,
    displayField: 'first',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    emptyText:'Select',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
           this.getStore().load();
        }

    }
});
```